# Is it more efficient to schedule a method to spawn enemies or use the update method of an Enemy cache?

Tags: objective-c, optimization, mobile, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2d for iPhone and I am wondering if it is more efficient to structure the logic of my code to spawn enemies using this method:

-(void) schedule:(SEL)selector interval:(ccTime)interval

or using the update in an EnemyCache class and verify each time if the time interval is met. Here is the code snippet that is called in the update method of the EnemyCache class (the relative time is an integer value that is updated by the GameScene at each update in the GameScene class - the GameScene update method call is scheduled with an interval of 1 second):

```
-(void) checkForPlayerCollisionsAndSpwanTime
{


    int count = [elements count];
    //CCLOG(@"count %i", count);
    Element* element;
    for(int i=0; i<count;i++){

        element = [elements objectAtIndex:i];
        NSAssert(element!=nil, @"Nil enemy");

        if (element.visible)
        {
            [element justComeDown];
            ShipEntity * ship = [[GameScene sharedGameScene]defaultShip];
            CGRect rect = [ship boundingBox];

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect([element boundingBox], rect)){
                [element doWhatever]; 
                element.visible=FALSE;
                [element stopAllActions];
            }       
        }
        else{
            if(element.spawnTime == relativeTime) {
                [self addChild:element]; 
                element.visible=TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The difference is that in this way at each update the **checkForPlayerCollisionsAndSpwanTime** method goes through the array of enemies. In the first way, via scheduling a selector to call a similar method, I could reduce the time spent by the CPU to look through the array and conditions.

I am not sure how costly is this call:

```
[self schedule:selector interval:interval repeat:kCCRepeatForever delay:0];
```

Looking through I see that calls this method (See below) but I wanted to ask in general what is your approach for this problem and whether I should keep using the EnemyCache update method or use the scheduleSelector methods.

```
-(void) scheduleSelector:(SEL)selector forTarget:(id)target interval:(ccTime)interval paused:(BOOL)paused repeat:(uint) repeat delay:(ccTime) delay
{
    NSAssert( selector != nil, @"Argument selector must be non-nil");
    NSAssert( target != nil, @"Argument target must be non-nil");

    tHashSelectorEntry *element = NULL;
    HASH_FIND_INT(hashForSelectors, &target, element);

    if( ! element ) {
        element = calloc( sizeof( *element ), 1 );
        element->target = [target retain];
        HASH_ADD_INT( hashForSelectors, target, element );

        // Is this the 1st element ? Then set the pause level to all the selectors of this target
        element->paused = paused;

    } else
        NSAssert( element->paused == paused, @"CCScheduler. Trying to schedule a selector with a pause value different than the target");


    if( element->timers == nil )
        element->timers = ccArrayNew(10);
    else
    {
        for( unsigned int i=0; i< element->timers->num; i++ ) {
            CCTimer *timer = element->timers->arr[i];
            if( selector == timer->selector ) {
                CCLOG(@"CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: %.4f to %.4f", timer->interval, interval);
                timer->interval = interval;
                return;
            }
        }
        ccArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(element->timers, 1);
    }

    CCTimer *timer = [[CCTimer alloc] initWithTarget:target selector:selector interval:interval repeat:repeat delay:delay];
    ccArrayAppendObject(element->timers, timer);
    [timer release];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a performance problem in your app? If not, the answer is: it doesn't matter. If you do, did you measure it and did the issue come from the method in question? If not, the answer is: you're looking in the wrong place.

In other words: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

If you still want to know, there's just one way to find out: measure both variants of the code and pick the one that's faster. If the speed difference is minimal (which I suspect it will be), favor the version that's easier for you to work with. There's a different kind of performance you should consider: you, as a human being, reading, understanding, changing code. Code readability and maintainability is way more important than performance in almost all situations.

No one can (or will) look at this amount of code and conclude "Yes, A is definitely about 30-40% faster, use A". If you are concerned about the speed of the method, don't let anyone tell you which is faster. Measure it. It's the only way you can be sure.

The reason is this: programmer's are notorious about making assumptions about code performance. Many times they're wrong, because the language or hardware or understanding of the topic have made big leaps the last time they measured it. But more likely they're going to remember what they've learned because once they've asked a question just like yours, and someone else gave them an answer which they accepted as fact from then on.

But coming back to your specific example: it really doesn't matter. You're much, much, much, much, much more likely to run into performance issues due to rendering too many enemies than the code that determines when to spawn one. And then it really, really, really, really, really doesn't matter if that code is run in a scheduled selector or a scheduled update method that increases a counter every frame. This boils down to being a subjective coding style preference issue a lot more than it is a decision about performance.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I hadn't found any reading explaining how the scheduler worked. I could have experimented but I was short of time and I prefered to ask to see if it was something sensible to look at. If you have any "mandatory reading" on this specific question please share.

Comment: @mm24 - no offense was meant here, more of a compliment to Steffen for his clarity on the subject. My general approach to optimization is in three phases. Phase 1 : Dont.  Phase 2 : if you suspect you may have to, investigate by measuring. Phase 3 : if you must, focus on high value areas, where a small improvement will bring large overall app behaviour improvement.